# JQGrid custom Add row with default value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a Jqgrid In asp.net mvc3 page . I want to create a custom "Add New " functionality .
On click of add new row a new set of textbox will be created with some default logical values.  I have created the new row but found some issue with reading the controls and setting the values in it .

As there is some logic related to controls of the newly added row I can't use inbuild jqgrid add functionality .

Code:

```
customAdd()
{ 
var rows = jQuery("#studgrid").getDataIDs(); 
row=jQuery("#stugrid").getRowData(rows[0]);

(In my first row I have added a new row ) row.colname1; row.colname2; // How I will check this control is of textbox type and set some default rule 
}
```

Comment: customAdd()
{
var rows = jQuery("#studgrid").getDataIDs();
 
    row=jQuery("#stugrid").getRowData(rows[0]);(In my first row I have added a new row )
   
 row.colname1; row.colname2; 

// How I will check this control is of textbox type and set some default rule
 
 }